echo printf output in two lines for some expressions instead of one
Using Debian 12 stable.
The following echo works as expected, ie. the hardcode label and the result of the expression are displayed in the same line
echo "unzip  version: $(unzip -v | head -1)"
# unzip  version: UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.

echo "JQ version....: $(jq --version)"
#JQ version....: jq-1.6

However for some utilities, their console version output seems to interfere with echo. The display is split in two lines in wrong order:
echo "dig version: $(dig -v)"
#DiG 9.18.28-1~deb12u2-Debian
#dig version:

printf "dig version%s\n" $(dig -v)
#DiG 9.18.28-1~deb12u2-Debian
#dig version

echo "SSMTP version: $(ssmtp -V)"
# sSMTP 2.64 (Not sendmail at all)
# SSMTP version:

Capture the result in a variable doesn't work either
DIG_VERSION="$(dig -v)"
# DiG 9.18.28-1~deb12u2-Debian

echo "Dig Version: --->$DIG_VERSION<---"
# Dig Version: ---><---

What is the reason and hopefully there is a fix.

jq --version prints to its stdout, so $(jq --version) manages to capture this output and everything works as you expect.
dig -v prints to its stderr. It probably should print to stdout, because it prints what you have requested and do expect (compare this answer); still it prints to stderr.
In echo "dig version: $(dig -v)", at first dig -v prints to its stderr, which usually (and certainly in your case) happens to be a terminal. Only when dig terminates, $() captures what dig has printed to its stdout: nothing. Then the command becomes echo "dig version: " and this gets executed.
You can redirect stderr to the open file description of stdout with 2>&1:
echo "dig version: $(dig -v 2>&1)"

Related:

What does 2>&1 do in command line?
Determine if output is stdout or stderr


Thanks very much for the very elegant solution in particlar for the background explanation.
